# Verificar se uma sequência de números está presente em outra

Tags: python

Tenho duas sequencias numéricas que possuem algumas sequências de dígitos semelhantes.

```
a = 0000000724050613
b = 07240001980055060113
```

**Exemplo**: as sequencias **724** e **506**, por exemplo, estão contidas em `a` e `b`

Quero saber como faço para verificar se essas sequências de números em `a` estão presentes em `b`.

Comment: Mas eles também possuem `13`, `000`, `07240`, e vários dígitos em comum. O que define essa similaridade? Tem que ser uma sequência de três dígitos? A maior sequência possível? Tem que ser diferente de 0?

Comment: Poderia ser a maior sequencia possível. Por exemplo: 07240, 000 e 506. Verificar se essas 3 sequencias em a também ocorrem em b.

Answer (score 1):

[ Resposta atualizada ] Fiz esse código abaixo que anda por uma variável de **X** posições **X** vezes, ou seja, uma variável de 5 posições é analisado 25 vezes e em cada vez ele verifica a **posição[1,2,3,4,5]** até a **posição[1,2,3,4,5] + a quantidade que a análise** está sendo repetida. É basicamente isso:

a = "12345"

```
analisado    | Quantidade de análise
1,2,3,4,5    | 1
12,23,34,45  | 2
123,234,345  | 3
1234,2345    | 4
12345        | 5
```

Dessa forma ele vai analisar todo o conjunto de A, ai é só usar um:
**if (analisado in b):**

```
'''script que verifica quais elementos de A estão contidos em B '''

a = "0000000724050613"
b = "07240001980055060113"

x=1
loop = len(a)
while loop>=x:
 y=1
 while loop>=y:
  if y-1+x>loop:
   y=loop
  else:
   sequencia = a[y-1:y-1+x]
   if (sequencia in b):
    print("A sequência {} está contida em b".format(sequencia))
  y=y+1
 x=x+1
```

Coloquei no meu GitHub: https://github.com/gabriel-gregorio-da-silva/estaContidoEmB

Esse script não tem filtros, portanto se o numero 7230 estiver contido no B, ele vai mostrar o 7,2,3 e 0 que estão contidos na primeira análise, depois o 72,23 e 30 que estão contidos na segunda análise, depois o 723,230 na terceira análise e depois o 7230 na quarta análise.

Você pode construir uma lógica de filtro, você pega os valores em cada análise e verifica se eles estão contidos na análise seguinte o 7, 2, 3 e 0 por exemplo estão contidos na segunda análise como 73, 23 e 30, ou seja, eles já seriam eliminados.

Ai na terceira análise, o 73, 23 e 30 seriam eliminados, já que eles estão na terceira como 723 e 230.

Na quarta análise, o 723 e o 230 seriam eliminados porque estão contidos como 7230.

Comment: é justamente analisar as combinações em comum, de forma autônoma. Talvez eu não consegui abstrair direito a pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode converter os valores de a e b em string e tratá-las da forma que desejar, exemplo:

**Passando para string:**

```
str(a);
```

**Encontrando o valor:**

```
result = re.search('This', test)
```

**Podemos extrair o resultado usando o método group:**

```
result.group(0)
'This'
```

**Você provavelmente está se perguntando sobre o método group e por que passamos zero para ele.É simples, e eu vou explicar.Veja só, padrões são organizados em grupos, desse jeito:**

```
>>> result = re.search ('(Th)(is)',test)
```

**Aqui há dois grupos dentro dos parenteses.Podemos extraí-los usando o método group.**

```
>>> result.group(1)
'Th'
>>> result.group(2)
'is'
```

**Depois de realizar os tratamentos pode converter de volta para numero:**

```
int('a');
```

---

**Referência:**

- [Manipulando strings em python](https://wiki.python.org.br/ManipulandoStringsComPython)